# Notation clarifcation

Tags: differential-geometry

If we compute the Lie Derivative of some tensor field $(2$ tensor $g)$, then we get some expression say:

$$\mathcal{L}_X(g) = 0\otimes dx+dy\otimes 0+d1\otimes dz$$

Do we just leave it like this? Or do we just say the Lie derivative is in fact $0?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like $0$ to me, so you can say the the Lie derivative is indeed 0.

Comment: How about $d1$ term?

Comment: The exterior derivative of a constant is 0, assuming that is what you mean when you write $d(1)$.